# Subset rows from dataframe based on an existing dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'd like the code to return the remaining rows after subsetting from another dataframe.

```
Month = c('January','February','March','April','May','June')
Names = c("Jack", "Steve", "CJ", "Polar", "Ren", "Vent")
Color = c("Red", "Grey", "Yellow", "Blue", "Yellow", "Pink")
df= data.frame(Month, Names, Color)

Month = ""
Names = c("Jack", "Steve", "CJ", "Polar", "Ren", "Vent", "Keegan", "Fabian")
Color = c("Red", "Grey", "Yellow", "Blue", "Yellow", "Pink", "Pink", "Red")
df2 = data.frame(Month, Names, Color)
```

`df$Month` is filled up while `df2$Month` will be an empty column. Essentially what I would like to do is to subtract `df` from `df2`. And it should return me

```
    
Month   Names  Color
1       Keegan  Pink
2       Fabian  Red
```

Comment: This is a one-liner: `dplyr::anti_join(df2, df, by=c("Names", "Color"))`

Comment: Oh its called an anti join, thanks for the help pal! @Taufi

Comment: Hi lets say that I have a lots of columns, it's going to be a hassle for me to name out all the column names and put them into the line, is there a way that will help me identify all the column names at once without entering them manually? @Taufi

Comment: Type `?colnames`. I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, yes I tried using colnames(df) and colnames(df2) but both of them return me 8 rows of vectors. I will settle with the previous solution for now, thanks again! @taufi